# Modify Bluetooth Chat Sample Code to connect with non-Android Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am making an App based on the Sample Bluetooth Chat given on the Official Android Developer website. My App works fine whilst chatting with another Android Phone. However, it does not work when I connect it to a non-Android Device (namely some electronic circuit that my team has made).
Internet Research has shown that the Sample Code is only meant to communicate between two Android Devices.
So, how do I change the Sample Code to make it work with other non-Android Devices as well.

Comment: Make sure they're using the same UUID?

Comment: (possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251026/android-connecting-to-a-non-android-device-via-bluetooth)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the Answer through analysing the source-code of the BlueTerm App. Effectively, I only needed to change the UUID that I was setting in the App from `fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66` to `00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"`

I'm not an expert on this area so I can't say WHY that is the case, but it does help solve my problem. The BlueTerm SourceCode is available on [Official Download Website of Pymasde](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/)

Comment: even google suggests this solution: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29 - crazy

Comment: Thank you a lot, I couldn't find any info about this and your answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

the UUID is specifically for serial port connection and it's a standard.